# Tips for making spaces work like tabs in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

At work we have the convention on using **4 spaces** for code indentation. I'm accustomed to using `tabs` for indentation, but want to follow the convention.

Note: it is not my intention to start a discussion on spaces vs tabs here.

I adjusted my Visual Studio settings to replaces tabs with 4 spaces, but I have some issues adjusting to using spaces.

For example:

- How can I easily un-indent code? with `tab` chararaters, I only
  needed to use <kbd>backspace</kbd> one time, with spaces I need to use <kbd>backspace</kbd>
  4 times.
- How can I make sure that there is always the correct amount of spaces
  (not three or five)?
- How can I navigate through my code as fast as I could with tabs? (arrow left or right jumps
  to the next indentation with tabs, but moves only a single position with spaces)
- How can I ignore whitespace changes when comparing files?

Idealy, I would like these 4-spaces for indentation to work equally to tab characters.

I work mainly with c# and XML-based files.

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Unindent code with Shift-Tab at the start of a line. Use "Reformat Document" to correct indentation, or make VS reformat a block when it's closed, or use a plugin that shows you indentation guides in the editor that will make it easier to spot when things don't align to them.

Comment: I'd also suggest pouring over the Options dialog to see how much of this is configurable or not, might be some of what I mentioned has to be enabled.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Arrow left key`/`Arrow right Key` will take you to the next non white space character. That's faster than just arrow left/right!

Comment: There really needs to be an add-in that just converts spaces to tabs on open, and then back to spaces on save (or even on download/check-in).

Comment: Also, `[Home]` toggles between the beginning of a line and the first non whitespace character. This is usually faster than navigating with the cursor keys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To un-indent, highlight the line and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Or just position to the beginning of the line and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Also, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will enter the correct number of spaces to align at the next 4-space boundary.

To make sure indentation is correct, you can highlight an area of code and select Edit -> Advanced -> Format Selection, or you can just go to the end of a block, remove the ending brace, and add it back. The IDE will reformat your code.

So, if you have this:

```
void foo()
{
  f();
     int q = 32;
   for (; q > 0; --q)
     {
    // really messed up indentation
   }
  }
```

Then deleting and re-adding that final `'}'` will reformat the entire method.

Comment: +1. There is also `Format Document` which works equally well (which is located at the same place as Format Selection). A note though, if there are any logical issues, for instance missing `{` or `}` the IDE formatting will not work.

Answer (score 13):

<sub>Such a shame that Visual Studio does not implement smart unindent. You can find this feature it even in the most simple free notepad-like editors.</sub>

Fortunately, to simplify auto-unindent with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>, there is an awesome plugin, [TabSanity](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ac4d4d6b-b017-4a42-8f72-55f0ffe850d7) by jedmao (Jed Hunsaker).

> This package causes the Visual Studio text editor to treat
>   tabs-as-spaces as if they were actually tabs. That is, the backspace
>   and delete keys, arrow key navigation and mouse cursor text selection
>   (coming soon) will not allow the caret to land within the spaces that
>   form a tab.

Note that it requires as dependency another cool plugin, [EditorConfig](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8bccfe2-650c-4b42-bc5c-845e21f96328)
.

Both are highly recommended for "tabs-as-spaces" text maniacs.

<sub>Happy coding!</sub>